# Why is my makemigrations not creating table

Tags: django, django-models

I know this question has been asked before ,but not resolved .When ever i run django makemigrations and migrate, it does not create a my table in the data base .I have done research but yet, do not understand why this is happening and how i can resolve it .Any one has faced such a problem before and resolved it .Please share your solution thanks in davance

Comment: What *does* it do?  Do you get an error message?  It's quite difficult to help without a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is partly why you're getting downvoted.  What don't the other answers resolve for you?

Comment: I do not get any error  when i run migration .The migration runs just fine ,but the table seems not created in the data base

Comment: Are you able to create and save model instances on the command line? You need to include your models.py and the details of any database inspection you're doing that you think means it's not operating as expected.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are required to make a migration do something.

1. python manage.py makemigrations (builds instructions), python manage.py migrate actually alters the db specified in your settings.py
2. You must have a db specified in settings.py
3. This looks at the apps added in settings.py, if you modify a models.py for an app not added in the settings then it won't show up.

Comment: sir the app is added in setting.py .My migration of my previous models worked just fine .until  the recent model .

Comment: And this same app has previously worked?  And are there no error codes in the migration?

Comment: Yes the app is working just fine .But facing problem in creating table in the data base for the new model i recently created .migrations runs with no errors ,but yet table not created for that model

Comment: I ma having same issue here, after adding 2 new models did end up finding a fix?